# Bolt hole terminology for "tight" and "loose" bolt holes

Tags: terminology

When a hole is created for a bolt, it might be "tight"; the intent is for the hole to be tapped. Or it might be "loose", and the intent is for the bolt to slide into the hole and attached to a nut on the other side.

What is the terminology for these two kinds of holes?

Comment: Hi Mark, has this been asked as a specific 3D printing question or should it be moved to Engineering.SE. As it stands now it is more a question fit for another Stack? I'd like to know the rational behind the question. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Oscar, I'm getting ready to ask a question about compensating for hole sizes when 3d printing and wanted to make sure I asked properly about a clearance hole (the "loose" one in my ignorance!).  If you think it's better to move, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hole designed for a screw/bolt to slide freely through is called a clearance hole. A hole that is designed to be tapped could be called a pilot hole.